# Media Queries not working properly

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've been trying to write some simple media queries, but I was stuck right after I started. It seems like media queries only work on text and not on divs and images.
This is my css code along with the html.

```css
 @media (max-width: 720px) {
   .logo {
     margin-top: 30px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     width: 100%;
   }
   <!-- only this piece of query works --> .text {
     border-bottom: 2px solid red;
   }
   .gif {
     clear: right;
   }
 }
 body {
   background-image: url('website/resources/images/body.png')
 }
 .logo_container {
   width: 700px;
   height: auto;
   margin-top: 60px;
   margin-bottom: 40px;
 }
 #logo {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
 }
 .text {
   font-size: 30px;
   margin-bottom: 60px;
 }
 .gif {
   float: right;
 }
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="logo_container">
    <img id="logo" src="logo.png"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="text">some text ...</div>
  <div class="gif">
    <img src="under_construction.gif"></img>
  </div>
</center>
```

Acording to this code image should strech to 100% of the window width right after window size comes under 720px and gif which float to the left of the text should clear its float and go under the image. But nothing happens, except text gets a red border.

I've tried some different formats of media queries, `@media () {}`, `@media screen () {}`, `@media only screen () {}`, `@media screen and () {}`, `@media only screen and () {}` but none of these seem to work for images and divs.

Here is my whole code:

http://pastebin.com/0bvUrZnU

Comment: Note that < center > is not supported in HTML5 - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Comment: Hi Orglce, I have put up an answer but could you confirm if you are trying to use html 5 and that way i can clean up your html aswell thanks

Comment: @ogrlce Updated my answer youw as missing a dot before text in your css and also float was still active because you need to cancel a float with float:none;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so your media queries are not great.

Firstly lets change media to  : `@media handheld,screen and (max-width: 720px)`

This will allow your query to be read across the board by DPI changes resolution changes it will even work in things like iframes and pretender box's and emulators it all basically.

Now also as a rule of thumb your media queries should be at the bottom of your style sheet. We do this because style sheets are read from top to bottom so all overriding styles should go underneath original style rule's.

so you want this :

You were missing a `.` before `text` and also use `float:none;` when canceling a `float`.

I have also tidied up your html a little also with `<img>` tags always define the `height` and `width` withing the tag itself like so `<img width="300" height="100" />` and then use css to override it. this is so the browser can render the image faster because it knows its proportion's & you should all ways have an `alt` attribute. finally images are not wrappers they do not need to end in `</img>` instead just finish it all off like this: `<img width="300" height="100" alt="iam an image and if i wanted to be responsive i should have max-width:100%; height:auto; as my CSS rule." />`

```css
body {
  background-image: url('website/resources/images/body.png')
}
.logo_container {
  width: 700px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.gif {
  float: right;
}
@media handheld,
screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  #logo {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .text {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  }
  .gif {
    float:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="logo_container">
    <img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="all images should have alts and use width and height" />
  </div>

  <div class="text">some text ...</div>

  <div class="gif">
    <img src="under_construction.gif" alt="all images should have alts and use width and height" />
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Thanks for really good answer but sadly, it still doesn't work. I have updated my questions with the whole code. Maybe I've missed some in the head or something like that?

Comment: will check it out works at my end that way and in the run code snippet

Comment: Glad it helped you out!

Answer (score 1):

on your desktop code you target logo as an id `#logo` and in your media query you target it as a class `.logo`

Comment: it could well have solved the problem if a typo was the only issue

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected but you have some problem in code inside your `media` query. You are referring it as `class` instead of `id`

```
@media (max-width: 720px) {
    /*this is id but you just referred it with .logo which isn't present*/
    #logo {
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /*only this piece of query works*/
    .text {
        border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    }

    .gif {
        clear: right;
    }
}
```

Comment: @orglce I've created a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/c0fan2ps/)** for you. Can you please explain what exactly you are looking for? because `width:100%` is set irrespective of screen size!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after css lint suggested to remove
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

I replaced that and media queries worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Most issues that I have come across with Media Queries not working as expected are due to the order they appear.  Sometimes they can get out of order unexpectedly, especially when changing from min to max or vice versa.

When using max-width, check to make sure all queries appear largest to smallest width (1200px, then 992px, etc).

When using min-width, check to make sure all queries appear smallest width to largest (576px, then 768px etc).

Comment: Can you provide your code on  what you have done so far?